# Check for multiple registry keys in batch file

Tags: batch-file

I need to check the registry for multiple keys before I start my program (they shouldn't exist). The widely spread solution for checking registry keys works for only one check since it sets global ErrorLevel to 1. The example below won't work correctly.

```
@echo off

reg query HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\mykey >nul
if %errorlevel% equ 0 (
    echo "mykey exists - do nothing"
) else (
    reg query HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\mykey2 >nul
     if %errorlevel% equ 0 (
         echo "mykey2 exists - do nothing"
    ) else (
         run my program
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using errorlevel like this will require [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html).You can try with [IF ERRORLEVEL](http://ss64.com/nt/if.html)

```
@echo off

reg query HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\mykey >nul
if %errorlevel% equ 0 (
    echo "mykey exists - do nothing"
) else (
    reg query HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\mykey2 >nul
     if errorlevel 1 (
         run my program
    ) else (
         echo "mykey2 exists - do nothing"
    )
)
```

Comment: This won't work and it also has a wrong logic behind the code.

Comment: @Himmel - I've deleted one redundant `equ`.

Comment: errorlevel will have a value of 1 no matter what once it's set to 1 so it will a false negative condition result in your case.

Comment: @Himmel , but on successful execution `reg` sets the errorlevel to 1?

Answer (score 0):

Get inspired by this example :

```
@echo off
cls & color 0A & echo.
Mode con cols=70 lines=5
Title Check Startup Registry Keys
Set TmpLogFile=TmpLogkey.txt
Set LogFile=Startup_key_Log.txt
If Exist %TmpLogFile% Del %TmpLogFile%
If Exist %LogFile% Del %LogFile%

Set mykey="HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run"^
^ "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run"^
^ "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon"^
^ "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer\Run"^
^ "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer\Run"^
^ "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options"

Echo.
ECHO                 **************************************
ECHO                        Please wait..........
ECHO                 **************************************

For %%K in (%mykey%) Do Call :Check_Key %%K %TmpLogFile%

Cmd /U /C Type %TmpLogFile% > %LogFile%
Start "" %LogFile%
Exit /b
::********************************************
:Check_Key
reg QUERY %1 >nul 2>&1
(
    if %errorlevel% equ 0 ( reg QUERY %1 /s
        ) else ( echo %1 ===^> Not found
    )
) >>%2 2>&1
::********************************************
```